# Mongodb - Small and Larger deployment

Tags: backup, restore, mongodump, mongorestore

I read the  following information from "https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/backups/"

"mongodump and mongorestore are simple and efficient tools for backing up and restoring small MongoDB deployments, but are not ideal for capturing backups of larger systems."

I want to know the definition of small and larger deployment in the perspective of mongodb context.